# Wildfly 8.2 Remoting - Too many channels open

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, remoting

below is my configuration for remoting and everything is working fine when I do remoting. The problem is at a certain point, there is too many channels open and because of this other remoting calls fail with this issue.

And to fix this issue I tried to close the context in a finally statement and get this issue:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting] 
    (Remoting "config-based-ejb-client-endpoint" task-9) 
EJBCLIENT000016: 
    Channel Channel ID c50b300b (outbound) of Remoting connection 
    29298b25 host/127.0.0.1:8080 can no longer process messages
...failed with exception -: 
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
        EJBCLIENT000027: No EJBReceiver available for node name
```

---

```
String info = "remote.connection.default";
props.put(info + ".host", StringUtils.substringBefore(url, ":"));
props.put(info + ".port", StringUtils.substringAfter(url, ":"));
props.put(info + ".username", "username");
props.put(info + ".password", "password");
props.put(info + ".connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "true");
props.put(info + ".connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
props.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
props.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", "true");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
```

How can I fix the issue? Am I missing a property? How can I close the ejb context without having this issue?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a static Map I was able to close the Context at a later time.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Could you post the code of your solution?

Comment: Basically Im reusing the context from the static map and close it after a certain amount of time that the context was not used so when I close it, there is nothing done in the background with this context. The right way would normally to close the context in a finally statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a static method

```
EJBClientContext.getCurrent().close();
```